# How to retain gameobject in DoNotDestory objects when game is restart

Tags: unity, c#

I have an empty object which is not destroy after the game is restarted.

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
```

I have some gameobject references in the script

```
public GameObject leaderboardPanel;
public GameObject addPointsPanel;
public GameObject updateButton;
```

When the scene is reloaded then all the above objects in inspector shows

```
Missing(GameObject)
```

[image]

after game is reloaded

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to flag those object as DontDestroyOnLoad too?

Comment: yes when game / scene is reloaded reference objects should also not get destory

Comment: So you called `DontDestroyOnLoad(leaderboardPanel)` or on the canvas that contains it?

Comment: leaderboardPanel is under canvas. DoNotDestroy is an Empty GameObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you unload a scene, any object in that scene that was not marked `DontDestroyOnLoad()` (or not parented under a root object marked this way) will be destroyed. It doesn't matter whether another object still holds a reference to it. If you didn't tell Unity you wanted it exempted from the scene unload, then it will be destroyed just like everything else in the scene. That leaves a hole where it used to be - the "Missing (Game Object)" links you're observing.

The reason that you *seem* to still see the object in your scene is because you're reloading the same scene. So that spawns *new copies* of the leaderboard, etc. But the leaderboard that exists in the current scene is *not* the one your object was referencing.

If you have a cluster of objects that all depend on one another, then if you mark one as `DontDestroyOnLoad`, you'll probably want to mark *all* of them that way, to ensure they get preserved together. One simple way to do this is to put them under one root object.

- Persistent Objects (Marked `DontDestroyOnLoad()`, contains your script referencing the others)

  - Canvas

    - Leaderboard Panel
    - etc...

By marking the root object as not to be destroyed, the other objects under it won't be destroyed either.

Using `DontDestroyOnLoad` this way gets messy though, because when you re-load the same scene, you'll still get new copies of these objects, in addition to the surviving object that evaded destruction when the scene was unloaded. [You can fix this by deleting the copies on scene load, or by moving these long-lived objects to their own scene that you load additively, and never unload/reload, so you never have to fuss with `DontDestroyOnLoad` in the first place](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/182028/39518).

Comment: you mean Objects in canvas which are going Missing after reload should also be marked as DoNotDestory object via assigning a script to the panel

Comment: I'd recommend instead that you put the whole canvas under a parent that is DontDestroyOnLoad, or that you put it in a scene that you do not unload.

Comment: DontDestroyOnLoad only works for root GameObjects or components on root GameObjects. - When DontDestoryOnLoad applied to object under canvas.

Comment: Which is why, I repeat, I recommend that if you use DontDestroyOnLoad, you put everything you want to persist under one root object, and use it on that.